# Another milk jug question

Tags: no-computers, decanting-problems

Recently there was a [jug pouring competition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96716/how-to-measure-5-litres-using-10l-7l-and-3l-vessels), and I got to thinking if this was the question with the most number of moves. It turned out that it was. If you have three different sized jugs all less than or equal to 10 litres, and only one of those jugs full, what target volume would give you the most number of steps.

You can get as many as 8 steps required. (10,9,2) → 8; (10,9,1) → 5; (10,9,1) → 4; and (10,7,3) → 5. So the question has pretty much the only interesting optimal result.

Here's another one for you (since I wrote the code already, it seems a waste not to use it).

> Starting with 15l in a 15l jug, an empty 11l jug, and an empty 4l jug try to get to 13l.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178368/worst-case-in-decanting-puzzles-pouring-water-from-one-jug-to-others

Comment: That's cool, @RobPratt! I thought someone must have looked at it.

Comment: While there are many different definitions of "a single step", the optimal solution to find $c$ litres from $a$ and $b$ litres-capacity jugs is solving the equation of either $ax-by=c$ or $bx-ay=c$ while minimizing the $x$ and $y$ which are usually describing the steps. (Well to be fair, the equation should be tweaked a bit for $c>a$ or $c>b$, but only constant steps will be done.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me 13 steps. Target is to remain with 2l in one of the jugs at the end and then work backwards.
Sequence of quantity is (15l, 11l, 4l)

(15l, 11l, 4l)

15,0,0

4,11,0

4,7,4

8,7,0

8,3,4

12,3,0

12,0,3

1,11,3

1,10,4

5,10,0

5,6,4

9,6,0

9,2,4

13,2,0

Comment: I got this, too, but you posted before I could type it up. Nice job.

Comment: Yes it's the same thing. I guess this is the only optimal way to go about this one

Answer (score 2):

Revised: (note: this is the same as @Vijay, who posted earlier, but I independently achieved it).
13 steps:

> ```
>   15L| 11L| 4L
>  ----|----|----
>   15 | 0  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   4  | 11 | 0
>  ----|----|---- 
>   4  | 7  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   8  | 7  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   8  | 3  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   12 | 3  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   12 | 0  | 3
>  ----|----|----
>   1  | 11 | 3
>  ----|----|----
>   1  | 10 | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   5  | 10 | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   5  | 6  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   9  | 6  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   9  | 2  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   13 | 2  | 0
>  ----|----|----
> ```

Earlier attempt:
There's bound to be a more optimal way, but here is one way to do it. 16 steps. Note that I dump water on the third to last step.

> ```
>   15L| 11L| 4L
>  ----|----|----
>   15 | 0  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   11 | 0  | 4
>  ----|----|---- 
>   11 | 4  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   7  | 4  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   7  | 8  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   3  | 8  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   3  | 11 | 1
>  ----|----|----
>   14 | 0  | 1
>  ----|----|----
>   14 | 1  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   10 | 1  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   10 | 5  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   6  | 5  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   6  | 9  | 0
>  ----|----|----
>   2  | 9  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   0  | 9  | 4     ----> dumped
>  ----|----|----
>   9  | 0  | 4
>  ----|----|----
>   13 | 0  | 4
>  ----|----|----
> ```

Comment: Looks good, but not optimal. Funnily enough I didn't allow dumping in my code. I should switch that on and see whether it changes things...