# I would like to buy 11 liters of milk please

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

This is somehow follow up question to [How to measure 5 litres using 10L, 7L and 3L vessels](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96716/how-to-measure-5-litres-using-10l-7l-and-3l-vessels)

You went to a farm to get some milk. You only need $11$ liters of milk and ask for it to the farmer, but our farmer has only left a filled $13$ liters of vessel with milk with two other empty $5$ and $9$ liters of vessels, he may of course give you his vessels for free. Help him and get for yourself 11 liters of milk without any other equipments available.

> At least how many times do you need to pour milk from one vessel to another vessel to buy 11 liters of milk in total?

You may use the table below;

```
+----+-----+----+----+
| #  | 13V | 9V | 5V |
+----+-----+----+----+
|  0 |  13 |  0 |  0 |
|  1 |     |    |    |
|  2 |     |    |    |
|  3 |     |    |    |
|  4 |     |    |    |
|  5 |     |    |    |
|  6 |     |    |    |
|  7 |     |    |    |
|  8 |     |    |    |
|  9 |     |    |    |
| 10 |     |    |    |
| 11 |     |    |    |
| 12 |     |    |    |
| 13 |     |    |    |
| 14 |     |    |    |
+----+-----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution takes

> 9 times
>  13 0 0
>  8 0 5
>  8 5 0
>  3 5 5
>  3 9 1
>  12 0 1
>  12 1 0
>  7 1 5
>  7 6 0
>  2 6 5
>  Now the 9L and 5L vessels contain 11L of milk in total. I just take them both (since there is no requirement that the requested volume should be in a *single* vessel).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's optimal, but I got a solution of $11$ steps after some trial-and-errors:

> `+----+-----+----+----+
>  | #  | 13V | 9V | 5V |
>  +----+-----+----+----+
>  |  0 |  13 |    |    |
>  |  1 |  8  |    |  5 |
>  |  2 |  8  |  5 |    |
>  |  3 |  3  |  5 |  5 |
>  |  4 |  3  |  9 |  1 |
>  |  5 |  12 |    |  1 |
>  |  6 |  12 |  1 |    |
>  |  7 |  7  |  1 |  5 |
>  |  8 |  7  |  6 |    |
>  |  9 |  2  |  6 |  5 |
>  | 10 |  2  |  9 |  2 |
>  | 11 |  11 |    |  2 |
>  +----+-----+----+----+`

Answer (score 3):

9 steps for 2 vessels and 10 steps for 1 vessel.

> 0  move 13 - 0 - 0
>
> 1  move  0 - 8 - 5
>
> 2  move  5 - 8 - 0
>
> 3  move  5 - 3 - 5
>
> 4  move 10 - 3 - 0
>
> 5  move 10 - 0 - 3
>
> 6  move  1 - 9 - 3
>
> 7  move  1 - 7 - 5
>
> 8  move  6 - 7 - 0
>
> 9  move  6 - 2 - 5
>
> 10 move 11 - 2 - 0

Answer (score 2):

As other answers show, 11 litres in a single container is achievable in 11 pours.  In addition, this is optimal, and in fact *every* reachable configuration can be reached with 11 pours, and (perhaps surprisingly) this can be checked with a manual search — there are only 28 reachable configurations.

Below is a full breadth-first search of the tree. It was constructed by going down the list in order; for each states, the ones that can be reached from it with one pour are listed; any that have already been reached are cancelled in [brackets], and the remaining new states are added to the bottom of the list (with a note of where they were reached from, and how many pours required).  It ends when there are no newly-reached states remaining.  Since the search is breadth-first, each state is reached by a path of minimal length.  This took about 10–15mins to do, plus another 5–10 for tidying up formatting.

```
#  from# pours state     goes to
1    –    0    13/0/0    4/9/0,   8/0/5
2    1    1    4/9/0     0/9/4,   [13/0/0], 4/4/5
3    1    1    8/0/5     0/8/5,   [13/0/0], 8/5/0
4    2    2    0/9/4     9/0/4,   [0/8/5],  4/9/0
5    2    2    4/4/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  9/4/0,    [4/9/0]
6    3    2    0/8/5     [8/0/5], 5/8/0,    [0/9/4]
7    3    2    8/5/0     [4/9/0], 3/5/5,    [13/0/0], [8/0/5]
8    4    3    9/0/4     [0/9/4], [8/0/5],  [13/0/0], [9/4/0]
9    4    3    4/9/0     [0/9/4], [13/0/0], [4/4/5]
10   5    3    9/4/0     [4/9/0], [4/4/5],  [13/0/0], [9/0/4]
11   6    3    5/8/0     [4/9/0], [0/8/5],  [13/0/0], 5/3/5 
12   7    3    3/5/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  [8/5/0],  3/9/1
13   11   4    5/3/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  10/3/0,   [5/8/0]
14   12   4    3/9/1     [0/9/4], 12/0/1,   [3/5/5],  [4/9/0]
15   13   5    10/3/0    [4/9/0], [5/3/5],  [13/0/0], 10/0/3
16   14   5    12/0/1    [3/9/1], [8/0/5],  [13/0/0], 12/1/0
17   15   6    10/0/3    1/9/3,   [8/0/5],  [13/0/0], [10/3/0]
18   16   6    12/1/0    [4/9/0], 7/1/5,    [13/0/0], [12/0/1]
19   17   7    1/9/3     [0/9/4], [10/0/3], 1/7/5,    [4/9/0]
20   18   7    7/1/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  [12/1/0], 7/6/0,
21   19   8    1/7/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  6/7/0,    [1/9/3]
22   20   8    7/6/0     [4/9/0], 2/6/5,    [13/0/0], [7/1/5]
23   21   9    6/7/0     [4/9/0], [1/7/5],  [13/0/0], 6/2/5
24   22   9    2/6/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  [7/6/0],  2/9/2
25   23   10   6/2/5     [0/8/5], [8/0/5],  11/2/0,   [6/7/0]
26   24   10   2/9/2     [0/9/4], 11/0/2,   [2/6/5],  [4/9/0]
27   25   11   11/2/0    [4/9/0], [6/2/5],  [13/0/0], [11/0/2]
28   26   11   11/0/2    [2/9/2], [8/0/5],  [13/0/0], [11/2/0]
```

Comment: Re "*there are only 28 reachable configurations.*", I was gonna the program I previously posted to check that today,  but I got sidetracked. It uses a BFS too.

Answer (score 1):

Targeting for 2 in one of the smaller vessels at the end

> [image: method description]

Answer (score 1):

8 iterations, and the final one for 11lt.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to puzzling SE :) I think the first step should be counted twice? Because you need to fill the second and third vessel.

Comment: It's wrong. How do you know that you've pured 5 litres in the 13v from the 9v in step 3?

Comment: technically step 3 is two steps — you pour 5L from the 5L into the 13L, and you pour 5L from the 9L into the 5L afterwards.

Comment: hello Newbee, welcome! you just need to fix step 3 :) the rest seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution requires 9 transfers.

A 9-transfer solution:

```
0       13      0       0
1       8       5       0
2       8       0       5
3       3       5       5
4       3       1       9
5       12      1       0
6       12      0       1
7       7       5       1
8       7       0       6
9       2       5       6
```

(5+6=11)

The shortest solution in which a container holds 11 L requires 11 transfers.

```
0       13      0       0
1       8       5       0
2       0       5       8
3       5       0       8
4       5       5       3
5       10      0       3
6       10      3       0
7       1       3       9
8       1       5       7
9       6       0       7
10      6       5       2
11      11      0       2
```

There could be other equally short solutions. This wasn't explored.

---

Solver:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );
use List::Util       qw( min sum );

sub solved_combined {
   my ($target, $vessels) = @_;

   my @quantities =
      grep { $_ > 0 && $_ <= $target }
         map { $_->[1] }
            @$vessels;

   return 0 if !@quantities;
   return 1 if grep { $_ == $target } @quantities;

   # This always takes time proportional to the square square of @quantities.
   # This can surely be optimized using dynamic programming techniques.
   my $iter = NestedLoops([
      map { [ 0, $_ ] } @quantities,
   ]);

   while ( my @selected = $iter->() ) {
      return 1 if sum(@selected) == $target;
   }

   return 0;
}

sub solved_single {
   my ($target, $vessels) = @_;
   return 0 + grep { $_->[1] == $target } @$vessels;
}

sub key {
   state $encoder = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->canonical;
   return $encoder->encode($_[0]);
}

sub solve {
   my ($target, $vessels, $solved) = @_;

   my @queue = [ $vessels ];
   my %seen;
   while (@queue) {
      my $states = shift(@queue);
      my $vessels = $states->[-1];

      return $states if $solved->($target, $vessels);

      for my $src (0..$#$vessels) {
         for my $dst (0..$#$vessels) {
            my $xfer = min(
               $vessels->[$src][1],                        # Available to xfer
               $vessels->[$dst][0] - $vessels->[$dst][1],  # Available capacity
            );

            next if $src == $dst || !$xfer;

            my $vessels = [ @$vessels ];
            $vessels->[$src] = [ $vessels->[$src][0], $vessels->[$src][1] - $xfer ];
            $vessels->[$dst] = [ $vessels->[$dst][0], $vessels->[$dst][1] + $xfer ];

            next if $seen{key($vessels)}++;

            push @queue, [ @$states, $vessels ];
         }
      }
   }

   return undef;
}

{
   my $target = 11;
   my $vessels = [
      # Capacity, Contents
      [ 13, 13 ],
      [  5,  0 ],
      [  9,  0 ],
   ];

   my $find_single;

   {
      my $states = solve($target, $vessels, \&solved_combined)
         or die("No solutions possible.\n");

      say join "\t", $_, map $_->[1], @{ $states->[$_] } for 0..$#$states;

      $find_single = !solved_single($target, $states->[-1]);
   }

   if ($find_single) {
      say "---";

      my $states = solve($target, $vessels, \&solved_single)
         or die("No solutions possible.\n");

      say join "\t", $_, map $_->[1], @{ $states->[$_] } for 0..$#$states;
   }
}
```

Comment: To get 11L in a single container, you can actually extend your 9-transfer solutions with 2 additional transfers (2-9-2 and 11-0-2), as pointed by @newbie.

Comment: @trolley813, I was interested in determining the minimum number of transfers, and my answer already shows it's 11 for a single container with 11 L. I also wanted to use a method that worked for any inputs (number of vessels, size of vessels, and initial contents). For both of these reasons, a way to extend the 5+6 L solution into a 11 L solution is of no interest to me, but thanks anyway!