How to measure 5 litres using 10L, 3L and 1L vessels
An 10 L container is full of water, and two others with the volumes of 3 L and 1 L are empty. You can mark the water levels in any vessel. How do you measure 5 L of water with them?

What's wrong with dumping out 1L five times?  Or dumping 3L once and IL twice?

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

No place to dump other than the existing jugs

"No place to dump other than the existing jugs" --- then the minimum amount in the 10L jug is 6L, while the other jugs can only make up 4L.

Are we allowed to throw away unwanted liquids？I mean, dump out 3L then pour it out. Then dump out another 3L, and dump 1L of it and dump back to the 10L vessel...

@tToE Would make the solution too trivial because you can just repeatedly throw away 1L to end up with any amount of liquid of whole-numbered liters.

It's possible if you can mark the liquid levels at each step, but I'm not sure if that's the intention.

How you define measure? Clearly there is no solution with the 10L container having 5L based on your response to dumping. Did you solve it?

You have to introduce something else for it to be possible. For example, if you could mark liquid levels, you could fill the smallest vessel first, mark the new liquid level in the 10L vessel as 9L, dump the 1L to the 3L vessel, mark the 1L level on that one, then do it again to end up with a fully marked 3L vessel, then do the same so all the levels from 6L to 10L are marked on the 10L vessel. Then you would know that if you completely fill up the small vessels and put the 1L one inside the 10L one, the portion up to the 6L level that's directly inside the 10L vessel must be 5L.

I googled it to figure out where the OP could have gotten the possible inspiration from. Looks like it's a common problem with 7L instead of 1L. It was probably a typo. Then that makes it a dupe: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96716/how-to-measure-5-litres-using-10l-7l-and-3l-vessels

Can you edit your post for clarity?  As you can see from the comments, nobody is able to sort this out within the given rules, though it is easily solved if we add new operations or if we change the volumes involved.

I think this question is a particular case of A general solution to the decanting problem? (aka jug-pouring, water-pouring). If you believe that Q&A doesn't answer yours, then please edit your question, making it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In order to make some sense of this question, I am going to interpret it as asking us to make a mark on the 10L container at the 5L level, without losing any water.
For a solution to exist, I am also going to assume that:

 The containers are cylindrical.

The first step is

 to transfer 2.5 litres from the 10L container to the smaller ones. You can do this by filling the 3L container from the 10L one, and then the 1L container from the 3L one. Finally pour exactly half the 1L container back into the 10L container. Simply pour it and stop when the water level just touches the bottom edge of the container as you pour. At this point the water level diagonally cuts the cylindrical container in half, so exactly 0.5 litres is returned. The large container now has 7.5 litres.

Finally you can put a mark at the 5L level as follows:

 Tilt the 10L container until is just about to pour out. Put a mark at the lowest part of the container that the water level reaches.

Here is an illustration:

 


I think this is the best answer I've seen here this year. Thank you!
